# Laravel session without cookies

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am writing a project in laravel and I need to use the session system but I have no access to cookies (So it needs to function without cookies)

I have got a rough idea on how I will do it i will include hidden fields in forms/get requests etc, but my question is how would i override laravels session system to fetch a session based on my custom token rather than the standard cookie token.

Comment: Can you explain how is it going to work? I mean, preserve "session id" (thats the most important part), since Laravel supports few drivers I guess you want to use database one, but you need to preserve session ID to make it work (it is saved in cookie as you know). What I mean, if user closes tab; session is gone also.

Comment: Anyway you want to start in app/http/kernel.php, thats where it all starts I think (test it yourself delete few lines see what happens), and from there you need to redo Session -> Illuminate/Session. Good luck.

Comment: To explain my idea i am planning to have the session id sent in the get part of the url or in post data in the form, im not too sure yet, i just need a way to 'fetch' that session based on my custom token.

Comment: Alright, I've done some reasearch, and it looks like you only need to create middleware that takes care of everything and simply use it on every request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I have already implemented something like this, but I don't know how to 'load' a session based off a custom token, I'm looking for something like Session::load($sessionid) or something along those lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel sessions without cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033060/laravel-sessions-without-cookies)