# Laravel sessions without cookies

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, authentication

I have an application which allows user to log in and add items to basket, however if user has cookies turned off, this functionality would no longer work. I've checked facebook and it turns out even they need cookies enabled to function.

So my question is is it even possible to handle regular login/add to cart functionality without cookies?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you on? You can change the session driver in the session configuration file over at `config/session.php`

Comment: Can't you create a database driven system instead?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.1, and my current session driver is set to db, however, since its not storing anything on the client side, my CSRF token verification is failing on me. So I'm trying to figure out a way to link the client and the server

Answer (score 1):

This is not only Laravel specific. Check http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php (specifically `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_only_cookies`) to see how you can enable the use of a _GET parameter instead.

As always, the documentation warns you that stealing a SESSION gets easy when you pass the ID via _GET.

But PHP should be automatically rewriting your URLs once you enable them, so no extra work required on your end, but I would personally keep the sessions restricted to a single IP and User-Agent - should make it hard for attackers.

Answer (score 0):

I can see Laravel tag in your question, so I'm giving you a link to all possible ways of using sessions in Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: But should this  allow my users to use the app fully if they have their cookies turned off, like completely off.

Comment: As per the 5.2 documentation, laravel stores a 'laravel_session' cookie containing the session instance ID for all of the drivers. Maybe except for array. Check /config/session.php